# Exchange series and integral in a complex context.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-integration

Let $a_{n},b_{n},c_{n}$ complex sequences and let $k>0$ a real parameter. 
 Assuming that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\sum_{m\geq1}\left|\frac{a_{m}b_{n}}{c_{m+n+k}}\right|<\infty\tag{1}
 $$ if $k>1/2
 $ and assuming also that $$\frac{1}{c_{m+n+k}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}f\left(z\right)z^{m+n+k}dz
 $$ where $a>0
 $ and $f$ is an holomorphic function. The question is:

> under which hypothesis can we exchange the integral with the double series?

I know that if we consider $$\sum_{n\geq1}\left|b_{n}\right|\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}\left|f\left(z\right)\right|\left|z^{m+n+k}\right|\sum_{m\geq1}\left|a_{m}\right|\left|dz\right|\tag{2}
 $$ and $$\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}\left|f\left(z\right)\right|\sum_{n\geq1}\sum_{m\geq1}\left|a_{m}b_{n}z^{m+n+k}\right|\left|dz\right|\tag{3}
 $$ and we prove that both converge, we can exchange. This problem comes out from a work of mine. I have to find the smallest $k
 $ such that we can exchange the summation and the integral signs. If I use $(2)$ and $(3)$ I get $k>1
 $ and this result is optimal, but I would like to keep $k>1/2
 $. Does there exist another way to prove the exchange?

Comment: Absolute convergence implies that the exchange is possible, but the same is true under the (much) weaker hypothesis that the Dominated Convergence Theorem holds. If you know that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ belong to some $L^p$ space you may use Holder's inequality to check that DCT holds. Hilbert's inequality could be useful, too, since a convolution seems to be involved.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio If we want to use DCT we have to take the modulus inside the integral (the sequences are in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$), and this essentially gives $(2)$ and $(3)$. Am I wrong?